# How to intercept the webview response in android

Tags: android, webview, server, response

I have a html form in webview, when i tap some button on it, it send request to server and server responds accordingly. I want to intercept the server response in android.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a webViewclient & override its methods":

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
// do write your code here
}
//some more methods

});
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, I wanted to intercept the action triggered by webview, like i want to know which button was tapped in webview. Do you know any way to handle this scenario?